# Insert cells in specific column in Table

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a Table with 3 thead.

I'm trying to insert cells in the second column.

I put the insertCell function as follows:

```
cell = row.insertCell(2);
```

but it doesn't work.

This is my code :

```js
function add() {
    j++;
    count++;
    var table = document.getElementById('table0');
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    cell = row.insertCell(1);
    text = count;
    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));


}
```

Here is my JSFiddle [code](http://jsfiddle.net/54pmo8oy/13/)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you trying to insert cells into the 2nd column of the existing row, or to add a new row and insert cells there?

Comment: I want to add new row and insert cell in the second column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index you pass to `row.insertCell(index)` must be less than or equal to `row.cells.length`.  In your case, since `row` is a brand new row, `row.cells.length` is `0`, so you must pass `0` or `-1`.

Consider the HTML for your table.  How would you write the HTML for a row containing a single cell, in the 2nd column?  You can't do it!  If there is a cell in the second column, there must also be a cell in the first column.

To create a new row in `table`, with a cell in the second column:

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var firstCell = row.insertCell(-1);
var secondCell = row.insertCell(-1);
```

To give it the *appearance* of having no cell in the first column, use CSS to git rid of the border and any other styles that make it look like a cell:

```
firstCell.className = "empty";
```

```css
.empty {
    border: 0 none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54pmo8oy/14/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear whether this is what you're trying to do, but hopefully it's close. Clicking the button will add a new cell to the second column with each click:

```
(function () {
    var count = 1,
        add = function () {
            var table = document.getElementById('table0'),
                row = table.rows[0],
                cell = row.insertCell(1),
                text = count;
            cell.innerHTML = text;
            count++;
        };
    document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
        add();
    });
    add();
}());
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6yejbLn/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Actually , I want to add cell in the column 'Distance ' in second row.